# Upload file to ftp with unique name in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, ftp, ftp-server

> I wrote below function to upload file to ftp.it's working properly but i need to get uploaded file name.I think ftp server should write file name in response,am i right?

```
   public static string UploadFileToFTP(string source,string destination)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(source);
    string ftpfullpath = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_url"].ToString();
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath+@destination);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_user"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_pass"].ToString());
    string[] jj = ftp.Headers.GetValues(0);
    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFileWithUniqueName;

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@source);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    ftpstream.Close();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();

    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_http_url"].ToString() + @destination + "/" + response.ToString();//response.?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the `Response` stream

```
string fileName = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Or better

```
string fileName;
using(s = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    fileName = s.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: it's return nullstring value!

Comment: @MehdiRostami ... and that seems to be so because the response `Stream` is empty!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're going all "bare" and using `FtpWebRequest`, this can be resolved with three LOC using `WebClient`, which returns a `byte[]` response:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_user"].ToString(),
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_pass"].ToString());

    byte[] response = webClient.UploadFile("ftp://address.toserver.com",
                                           WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFileWithUniqueName, 
                                           "PathToLocalFile");
    var fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Comment: I believed that the server was supposed to answer back with the name of the file it chose.

Comment: @user35443 You're absolutely right. Edited my answer.

Comment: What do you get for `fileName`? A `null`?

Comment: @MehdiRostami Monitor the request using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), see if the server responses with anything

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov ,i tried fiddler,it doesn't monitor ftp protocol.i tried two different ftp but in your choice response is null.in my choice ftpresponse include ftp messages and details and ResponseStream is null.

Comment: @Mehdi See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/httpfiddler/jVh5PN-jNPw)